# DirectX what is a CounterResource?

Tags: directx, directx-12

In `ID3D12Device::CreateUnorderedAccessView method` you can specify a `ID3D12Resource *pCounterResource`. I understand that this is a another Buffer that contains an atomic counter.

**Q: For what is this counter used? How can it be accessed from HLSL?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are used for consume and append buffers.